# Problem with Android licensing service

Tags: android

I implemented Licensing Service in my application using the sample given with licensing module. I am using the standard ServerManagedPolicy. I have not changed anything in the policy and it actually works fine. I have following questions.

1. Sometimes, this happens randomly though, it says that application is not licensed and asks for buying it and then I try again it works fine. So few times, it will say, app is not licensed. I have seen this both on real phone and emulator.  This is a serious concern, because if the user who buys the app later on see the popup that app is not licensed, he is gonna get irritated. May I please know what is wrong with the standard `ServerManagedPolicy` code.
2. For a paid app, is the standard `ServerManagedPolicy` implementation given in the sample code enough, or do you recommend to tweak it and add / modify some checks.

Comment: Regarding part 1, I have no insight except to say that my users have experienced this as well on my app. I've also been in touch with the developers of another popular app (Baby ESP) who have experienced the same thing. The way we've both independently "solved" it is to display a message telling the user to try again a few more times and let us know if the problem persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sometimes happens when licensing is unable to access the market for validation.

There's an issue with the default SetValidityTimestamp code where the default VT value is returning null.

See [this link](http://code.google.com/p/marketlicensing/issues/detail?id=22) for details and a fix.  I've implemented this in my own apps and have not seen the issue since or had any market reports of it.

Comment: Thanks CodeChimp, this is very valuable information. I will try implementing the change with 1 week grace period. I have seen many people suggesting to do something different than standard ServerManagedPolicy to implement security. Even the sample code says inside checkLicense(). "Try to use more data here.ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack." What else can be done, any suggestions. Any sample code or URL is appreciated. So basically, I am requesting more inputs on question 2 in my post. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Implementing Market license checking API is a waist of time from my experience.

My game, Elastic World, got cracked a few hours after being on the market.
There's an android application called Lucky Patcher that cracks any APK that uses Market licensing API.

In the implementation of market licensing, I did everything by the book, following all google's recommendations, but Lucky Patcher always cracked the protection. I spent a couple of days on this trying several approaches, different kinds of obfuscation, placing the validation code in other areas of execution, but nothing worked.

Comment: Pedro, I see that Elastic World has a free and a paid version, and World Cup Soccer Challenge is only free with in-app purchase.  Does this mean that you have given up on LVL entirely?  (I'm about to release my first app, with 27 years total dev time, and wondering how best to do it.  If LVL's just no good at all, then in-app upgrade [my first instinct] may be the way to go; let the pirates pirate and just stay ahead of them with new features.)  [p.s. i'd download it now but my device is awaiting a repair part.]